# True or False modulo calculator

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

True or false:

a) $a ≡ b$ (mod m) and $n | m ⇒ a ≡ b$ (mod n) ($n$ is a factor of $m$): This is true because $a = b + mk = b + n \bullet l \bullet k$.

b) $a ≡ b$ (mod m) $⇒ a^2 ≡ b^2$ (mod $m^2$): This is also true

c) $a ≡ b$ (mod m) and $a ≡ b$ (mod n) $⇒ a ≡ b$ (mod $[m, n]$) : I have no idea

d) $(10^{50} − 1)^{12} ≡ 6$ (mod 3) : I'm stuck too!

Note: $[m, n]$ means least common multiple.

Please check if my proof is correct. For c and d please give me advice on how to prove/disprove! Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure b) is true?  What if $m=3, a=8, b=2$?

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you, that's why I need you guys to double check with me too because I'm looking for counterexamples!

Comment: For the last one...what is $10\pmod 3$?  For $c)$, note that $(a-b)$ is a common multiple of $m,n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of a) is essentially correct, but you should say what $l$ is.  On a formatting note, don't use `\bullet` for multiplication.  In this case, you could just write $nlk$, but if you want an operator symbol, use `\cdot`.

You are wrong on b), as I noted in a comment.

For c) think about what the lest common multiple is in terms of the prime factorizations of $m$ and $n$.

For d) you should realize that in addition and multiplication modulo $n$ you can replace any number $a$ by another number congruent to $a$ modulo $n$.  (Caveat: this doesn't work for exponentiation.  You can replace the base, but not the exponent.
You'll learn how to handle the exponent in a little while.)

Answer (score 0):

For (c),  just the definition.  There are integers $ p, q $ such that $a-b = mp= nq.$ This shows (c) is true.

For (d) the statement is equivalent to  $o \equiv 0$ mod 3, which is true.